# C# Webbrowser navigating links in order

Tags: c#, navigation, browser

I'm trying to teach myself C# and to start I'm trying to convert a program I originally wrote in Autoit.

I'm using a Windows Application Form and the program is suppose to take one or two links as input. Navigate to those to pages, grab some links from a table, then visit each of those pages to grab some content.

If only one link is entered it seems to go to that page and grab the links from a table like it is suppose to. If two links are entered it seems to only grab the links from the second table.

So if two links are passed this method

```
    private void getPageURLList(string site1, string site2)
    {
        getPageURLList(site1);
        getPageURLList(site2);           
    }
```

Calls the same method that gets called when there is only one link

```
    private void getPageURLList(string site)
    {
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += createList;
        webBrowser.Navigate(site);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is "Navigate" is getting called a second time before createList even starts the first time.

The reason I am using WebBrowser is because these pages use Javascript to sort the links in the table so HTTPRequests and the HTMLAgilityPack don't seem to be able to grab those links.

So I guess my question is: **How can I keep my WebBrowser from navigating to a new page until after I finish what I'm doing on the current page?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a bool variable to know when the first proccess has completed. And then start the other. Application.DoEvents() will help you.

Note that all this events run in the main thread.

Comment: I have tried using a bool to do that, but either it didn't work or I was putting it in the wrong place. I'll have to look into Application.DoEvents() to see if that fixes my issue.

Comment: in document completed : jobDone = true; and in code getPageURLList(site1);                                               jobDone = false;
while(!jobdone){ApplicationDoEvents();} getPageURLList(site2);  search it you will find it

Comment: These seems to have fixed it. It's running both links.  It runs the second link a second time, but that's probably an issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your documentcompleted event you do your link processing.  At the end of the link processingyou tel the browser to navigate to the next url